# How to format time.Since().String()?

Tags: go, time, formatting, string-formatting

What I have -> 1m16.044455998s

What I want -> 1m16s without milli-, micro-, nano- seconds.

Comment: By converting it to a datetime, you can get localized formats:
new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm");

Comment: Check out [time#Duration.Round](https://godoc.org/time#Duration.Round) method. And its example.

Comment: @AshwinGolani I think you may be thinking of C#, not Go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
time.Since(t1).Truncate(time.Second).String()
```

Check this go playground link for an example:
https://play.golang.org/p/x7k9zuuqpRp